# How can i change the speed on my Timer() during my game?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, timer, illegalstateexception

I made a game that counts how many times you can hold a ball (rectangle) in the air. The problem is that I want to let the ball move faster every time. The initial speed is 10 and I want it to count down every time the ball goes up again (the lower the "speed"-variable the faster te real speed).

But when the ball needs to go faster i get an IllegalStateException on the line where i do this: "spelTimer.schedule(panel.spelTask, 0, speed);" how can i solve the problem?

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;

    import javax.swing.*;

    public class Spel extends JPanel implements KeyListener {

    public Rectangle screen, ball, block;
    public Rectangle bounds;
    public JFrame frame;
    public SpelTimerTask spelTask;
    public boolean down, right, starten = false;
    public JButton start;
    public int counter = 0;
    public JLabel score;
    public static int speed = 10;
    public static java.util.Timer spelTimer;
    public static Spel panel;

    public Spel(){
        super();
        screen = new Rectangle(0, 0, 600, 400);
        ball   = new Rectangle(0, 0, 20, 20);
        bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, 600, 400);
        block = new Rectangle(bounds.width/2, bounds.height-50, 40, 10);
        frame = new JFrame("Super tof spel van Stan \u00a9");
        spelTask = new SpelTimerTask();
        score = new JLabel("0");
        score.hide();
        add(score);
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        start = new JButton("Start");
        start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                starten = true;
                ball   = new Rectangle(0, 0, 20, 20);
                start.setFocusable(false);
                start.hide();
                score.show();
            }
        });
        add(start);
    }

    class SpelTimerTask extends TimerTask{
        public void run(){
            repaint();

            if(starten){
            moveBall();
            frame.repaint();
            }
        }
      }

      public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        bounds = g.getClipBounds();
        g.clearRect(screen.x, screen.y, screen.width, screen.height);
        g.fillRect(ball.x, ball.y, ball.width, ball.height);
        g.fillRect(block.x, block.y, block.width, block.height);
      }

      public void moveBall(){
        if (right) ball.x+=1;
        else ball.x-=1;
        if (down)  ball.y+=1;
        else ball.y-=1;
        if (ball.x > (bounds.width - ball.width)) {
            right = false; 
            ball.x = bounds.width -  ball.width; 
        }
        if (ball.y == (bounds.height - ball.height - 10) && ball.x > block.x-20 && ball.x < block.x+40) { 
            down  = false; 
            ball.y = bounds.height - ball.height - 10;
            counter++;
            if(speed > 2){
                speed -= 1;
                spelTimer.schedule(panel.spelTask, 0, speed);
            }
        }
        if (ball.y > (bounds.height - ball.height)) {
            start.show();
            score.hide();
            counter = 0;
        }
        if (ball.x < 0) { 
            right = true; 
            ball.x = 0; 
        }
        if (ball.y == 0){ 
            down  = true; ball.y = 0; 
        }
        block.y = bounds.height-10;
        score.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
      }

      public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
          if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT && block.x > 0) {
              block.x -= 20;
          }

          if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT && block.x < (bounds.width - block.width - 20)) {
              block.x += 20;
          }
      }

      public void keyTyped(KeyEvent evt){  }
      public void keyReleased(KeyEvent evt){ }

      public void startActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
          starten = true;
      }

      public static void main(String arg[]){
        spelTimer = new java.util.Timer();
        panel = new Spel();

        panel.down = true;
        panel.right = true;

        panel.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        panel.frame.setSize(panel.screen.width, panel.screen.height);
        panel.frame.setContentPane(panel); 
        panel.frame.setVisible(true);

        spelTimer.schedule(panel.spelTask, 0, speed);
      }
}
```

Comment: [This article](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/timertask/java-timer-and-timertask-example-tutorial/) is about timers and timertasks.  Maybe it can help you find your answer.

Comment: Also, part of your problem may be the way you have spelTask set up.  You initialize the class one in the constructor, however, you try to access the one within panel on the line that's throwing an error.  That would be fine if spelTask was static I believe; otherwise you should be calling spelTimer.schedule(spelTask, 0, speed); I would think.

Comment: Can you give me concrete code how to solve this?

Comment: Not at the moment, I left a comment instead of an answer because I don't have a Java environment to test on at the moment and wouldn't have a way to verify that my fix actually worked.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got to a Java environment.

First, that error you're getting indicates that you're trying to schedule a task already scheduled. So you need to cancel it.  This brings up a small problem in that after something is canceled, it can't be restarted.  So you need to create a new task, and schedule it.

Your code here:

```
if(speed > 2){
    speed -= 1;
    spelTimer.schedule(panel.spelTask, 0, speed);
}
```

I modified it to:

```
if(speed > 2){
    speed -= 1;
    panel.spelTask.cancel();
    panel.spelTask = new SpelTimerTask();
    spelTimer.schedule(panel.spelTask, 0, speed);
}
```

In my test that fixed the issue.

Just as a further expansion on this topic, to prevent having to make a new task every time you want to change speed, you could instead multiply your movement changes by your speed instead.

**Edit:** As requested, here is a modification to use a speed multiplier instead of changing the timer schedule speed.  I ended up actually going with a 1 + (1*speed) instead of a 1 * speed, allows for a more gradual change in speed.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Spel extends JPanel implements KeyListener {
    public Rectangle screen, ball, block;
    public Rectangle bounds;
    public JFrame frame;
    public SpelTimerTask spelTask;
    public boolean down, right, starten = false;
    public JButton start;
    public int counter = 0;
    public JLabel score;
    private final static int interval = 1000/60;
    public static int speed = 0;
    public static java.util.Timer spelTimer;
    public static Spel panel;

    public Spel() {
        super();
        screen = new Rectangle(0, 0, 600, 400);
        ball   = new Rectangle(0, 0, 20, 20);
        bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, 600, 400);
        block = new Rectangle(bounds.width/2, bounds.height-50, 40, 10);
        frame = new JFrame("Super tof spel van Stan \u00a9");
        spelTask = new SpelTimerTask();
        score = new JLabel("0");
        score.setVisible(false);
        add(score);
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        start = new JButton("Start");
        start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                speed = 0;
                starten = true;
                ball   = new Rectangle(0, 0, 20, 20);
                start.setFocusable(false);
                start.setVisible(false);
                score.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        add(start);
    }

    class SpelTimerTask extends TimerTask {
        public void run(){
            repaint();

            if(starten){
                moveBall();
                frame.repaint();
            }
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        bounds = g.getClipBounds();
        g.clearRect(screen.x, screen.y, screen.width, screen.height);
        g.fillRect(ball.x, ball.y, ball.width, ball.height);
        g.fillRect(block.x, block.y, block.width, block.height);
    }

    public synchronized void moveBall() {
        if (right) ball.x+=(1 + 1 * speed);
        else ball.x-=(1 + 1 * speed);
        if (down)  ball.y+=(1 + 1 * speed);
        else ball.y-=(1 + 1 * speed);
        if (ball.x >= bounds.width) {
            right = false;
        }
        if (ball.y >= (bounds.height - ball.height - 10)) {
            if  (ball.x > block.x-20 && ball.x < block.x+40) {
                down  = false; 
                ball.y = bounds.height - ball.height - 10;
                counter++;
                if(speed < 10){
                    speed += 1;
                }
            } else {
                start.setVisible(true);
                score.setVisible(false);
                starten = false;
                counter = 0;
            }
        }
        if (ball.x <= 0) { 
            right = true;
        }
        if (ball.y <= 0){ 
            down  = true;
        }
        block.y = bounds.height-10;
        score.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
        if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT && block.x > 0) {
            block.x -= 20;
        }

        if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT && block.x < (bounds.width - block.width - 20)) {
            block.x += 20;
        }
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent evt) {}
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent evt) {}

    public void startActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        starten = true;
    }

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        spelTimer = new java.util.Timer();
        panel = new Spel();

        panel.down = true;
        panel.right = true;

        panel.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        panel.frame.setSize(panel.screen.width, panel.screen.height);
        panel.frame.setContentPane(panel); 
        panel.frame.setVisible(true);

        spelTimer.schedule(panel.spelTask, 0, interval);
    }
}
```

Some key notes here:

1. I changed all of your boundary checks.  Since the ball isn't always traveling 1 x and 1 y at a time, it won't perfectly hit the sides of the screen every time.  So the change was to check to see if the block was at or over the bounds.  You could go back and change it so that the position was readjusted if it goes over bounds, but that could cause other problems.
2. I changed moveBall to a synchronized method since I had a weird case that the moveBall appeared to be called twice simultaneously.
3. I changed the timer interval to 1000/60.  I did this because the typical human eye can only track movements less than 60Hz (60 changes a second).  Thus this time should be right at the threshold of people not being able to see the changes; giving the ball a smooth movement.

If there's something you don't understand about my changes I'd be happy to discuss them in the comments.

Comment: can you show met how to multiply my movement changes by my speed in code?

Comment: @user3275947, does that help?  The way you did it and the way I did it are just two of the many possible ways to go about this; but I hope my answer was able to solve your question.  Beyond doing it this way, I can think of one other decent way off the top of my head to do this and that would be to use a loop and a sleep function.